# What is the smallest width a US check can be?

Tags: united-states, check

From googling, I understand that checks need to have 8 things in them;

Bank Name, Customer Name, Date, Amount in Numbers & Words, Signature Mark, MICR Routing & Account info line.

Most of the personal checks are 6" wide & about 2.75" high.

My question is, can they be 4" wide? Any examples in use would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of a 4” check over a 6” check? Who cares?

Comment: @quid in US, a check in its whole can be printed at home. A standard letter size paper gives 3 6" checks & a waste of paper. A 4" check can go upto 10 checks in same paper. In any case, the question is, are there any examples of smaller than 6" checks written/used. Clearly, I asked, so I care.

Comment: As a practical matter, it could be anything your bank (and the bank it's deposited in) is willing to accept.  Larger than standard personal check sizes are fairly common, from businesses and the IRS.  At least IIRC: it's been a few years since I got a physical check from them, but they used to be the size of old computer punch cards.

Comment: @jamesqf, I think that's the question the OP is asking: what is the acceptable size range.

Comment: @spuck: Of course, and that's probably going to depend on individual banks.

Comment: You can try it out and deposit them to yourself and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this [check form publisher's handbook](https://www.troygroup.com/media/files/MICR-Basics-Handbook.pdf) (PDF), ANSI standard "Understanding and Designing Checks – ANSI X9/TG-2" mandates a minimum check size of 6" width and 2.75" height. See document page 1-3 (PDF page 7).